# iPhone app icon size when validating builds in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios5, app-store

I have a question when I am validating distribution build in Xcode.

I got the following error from Xcode
[image]

From this message, I guess my icon size is not right. However, I checked the image size several times, for the icon.png, the size is 57x57, while for the high resolution icon@2x.png, the size is 114x114.
[image]

So I also tried to make the icon again for several times, but I still get this message.

Is anyone know what happened here? Thanks!

Comment: btw, I built the app and tested on my iPhone 4, the high resolution icon did show well.

Comment: You need to download and install Application Loader 2.5.1. http://onesidebrain.blogspot.com/2012/02/iconpng-dimensions-0-x-0-dont-meet-size.html

Answer (score 1):

Please select the targets and summary and set the app icon there.If it is iphone add 57*57 and  ipad 72*72(size).  I think this would solve the  problem.